# Discord.js bulkDelete giving error "The messages must be an Array, Collection, or number."

Tags: discord.js

So I'm trying to create a command where you delete a certain amount of messages but it's giving an error "The messages must be an Array, Collection, or number.".

I looked on YouTube at other tutorials and such and they're doing the same thing. Why is this happening?

```
message.channel.bulkDelete(Math.floor(clearAmount)).then(() => {
    message.channel.send(`Deleted ${Math.floor(clearAmount)} messages.`).then(msg => msg.delete(3000)); 
});
```

Comment: What is stored in your clearAmount variable ? Could you print the variable ? and try to see what `Math.floor(clearAmount)` returns ?

Comment: I realised I was doing Math.floor to !clear, thanks for the help